# vb.net multiple ratings on button click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have portal kind of website where users finds list of hospitals. Now I want users to rate any hospitals. Here I have 6 different kind of ratings for 1 hospitals. I want users first to select all this ratings & when they click on submit then only it should insert in to database. And also only users who logged in to website should be able to rate. I have created users login/registration page & users are able to login to website perfectly but now how to integrate all this I have no idea. Please help me. This sound simple but since I am new to vb development I am getting problems...

rating aspx

```
 <!--star-left-starts--><div class="star-left">
                        <div class="star-rating1">
                            <strong>Resonability Of Charges</strong><br />
                            <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager2" runat="server">
                            </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
                            <cc1:Rating ID="Rating2" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" OnChanged="money" runat="server"
                                StarCssClass="Star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="Star"
                                FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar" MaxRating="10" CurrentRating="1">
                            </cc1:Rating>
                        </div>


                        <div class="star-rating2">
                            <strong>Staff Behaviour</strong><br />
                            <cc1:Rating ID="Rating3" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" OnChanged="behaviour" runat="server"
                                StarCssClass="Star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="Star"
                                FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar" MaxRating="10" CurrentRating="1">
                            </cc1:Rating>
                        </div>


                        <div class="star-rating3">
                            <strong>Admission Procedure</strong><br />
                            <cc1:Rating ID="Rating4" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" OnChanged="admission" runat="server"
                                StarCssClass="Star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="Star"
                                FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar" MaxRating="10" CurrentRating="1">
                            </cc1:Rating>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--star-left-ends-->



                    <!--star-right-starts--><div class="star-right">
                        <div class="star-rating4">
                            <strong>Proper Information</strong><br />
                            <cc1:Rating ID="Rating5" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" OnChanged="information" runat="server"
                                StarCssClass="Star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="Star"
                                FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar" MaxRating="10" CurrentRating="1">
                            </cc1:Rating>
                        </div>


                        <div class="star-rating5">
                            <strong>Hygine Standards</strong><br />
                            <cc1:Rating ID="Rating6" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" OnChanged="hygine" runat="server"
                                StarCssClass="Star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="Star"
                                FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar" MaxRating="10" CurrentRating="1">
                            </cc1:Rating>
                        </div>


                        <div class="star-rating6">
                            <strong>Treatment Satisfactions</strong><br />
                            <cc1:Rating ID="Rating7" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" OnChanged="treatment" runat="server"
                                StarCssClass="Star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="Star"
                                FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar" MaxRating="10" CurrentRating="1">
                            </cc1:Rating>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--star-right-ends-->


                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div><!--star-rates-ends-->
```

rating vb

```
Protected Sub money(sender As Object, e As RatingEventArgs)
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString
        Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("insert into ratings(charges)values(@Rating)")
                Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter()
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating", e.Value)
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    con.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Charges(sender As Object, e As RatingEventArgs)
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString
        Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("insert into ratings(behaviour)values(@Rating)")
                Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter()
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating", e.Value)
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    con.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub admission(sender As Object, e As RatingEventArgs)
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString
        Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("insert into ratings(admission)values(@Rating)")
                Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter()
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating", e.Value)
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    con.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub behaviour(sender As Object, e As RatingEventArgs)
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString
        Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("insert into ratings(behaviour)values(@Rating)")
                Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter()
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating", e.Value)
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    con.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
    End Sub
    Protected Sub information(sender As Object, e As RatingEventArgs)
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString
        Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("insert into ratings(information)values(@Rating)")
                Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter()
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating", e.Value)
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    con.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub hygine(sender As Object, e As RatingEventArgs)
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString
        Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("insert into ratings(hygine)values(@Rating)")
                Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter()
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating", e.Value)
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    con.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub treatment(sender As Object, e As RatingEventArgs)
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString
        Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("insert into ratings(treatment)values(@Rating)")
                Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter()
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating", e.Value)
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    con.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
    End Sub
```

Login code vb

```
Private Sub hospital_details_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim var, Type As String
        If Not HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("chkusername") Is Nothing Then
            var = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies("chkusername").Value)
        End If

        If Not HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("User_Type") Is Nothing Then
            Type = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies("User_Type").Value)
        End If

        Dim LogIn, LogOut, listup As Control
        Dim BtnProfile As Button = Page.Master.FindControl("myAccount")

        LogIn = Master.FindControl("login")
        LogOut = Master.FindControl("logout")
        listup = Master.FindControl("list")

        'not login
        If HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("chkusername") Is Nothing Then
            listup.Visible = True
            LogIn.Visible = True
            LogOut.Visible = False
            BtnProfile.Visible = False

            'login
        Else
            LogOut.Visible = True
            BtnProfile.Visible = True
            LogIn.Visible = False
            listup.Visible = False

        End If
End Sub
```

UPDATE ERRORS
[image]

UPDATED CODE ON Button Click

```
Private Sub sendReview_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles sendReview.Click
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString
        Dim Mrating2, Mrating3, Mrating4, Mrating5, Mrating6, Mrating7 As String
        Mrating2 = Rating2.CurrentRating
        Mrating3 = Rating3.CurrentRating
        Mrating4 = Rating4.CurrentRating
        Mrating5 = Rating5.CurrentRating
        Mrating6 = Rating6.CurrentRating
        Mrating7 = Rating7.CurrentRating
        Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("insert into ratings(hospitalID,charges,behaviour,admission,information,hygine,treatment)values(@hospitalid,@Rating2,@Rating3,@Rating4,@Rating5,@Rating6,@Rating7)")
                Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter()
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hospitalID", generalID.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating2", Mrating2)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating3", Mrating3)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating4", Mrating4)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating5", Mrating5)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating6", Mrating6)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating7", Mrating7)
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    con.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Here Can you please tell me how many columns your ratings table has?

Comment: @PiyushKhatri I have made 6 different columns for all 6 types of ratings & one columns which gets hospital id of each rating attempt & one for usersId which gets record of users who rated.

Comment: Yes, so that's correct. You can try to insert single row instead of different queries like, insert into ratings(userID, hospitalID, rating1, rating2, rating3...) values (userid, hospitalid, r1, r2, r3...)

Comment: @PiyushKhatri How do I pass values in queries with parameters?

Comment: I think you already pass parameters to your individual queries. So instead of individual queries, just make one and pass all parameters.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri In my all individual queries I am passing same parameters as Rating but how to do it when will combine it to one on ButtonClick. Please post answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like below,

```
Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString
Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("insert into ratings(userid,hospitalid,charges,behaviour,admission,information,hygine,treatment)values(@userid,@hospitalid,@Rating1,@Rating2,@Rating3,@Rating4,@Rating5,@Rating6)")
        Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", userid)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hospitalid", hospitalid)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating1", Rating1.value)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating2", Rating2.value)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating3", Rating3.value)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating4", Rating4.value)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating5", Rating5.value)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating6", Rating6.value)
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Got some errors in. Please look at update in my post

Comment: I understood error of hospitalID. But what about Ratings?

Comment: Check properties of rating control. May be instead of value you will have another property to get value.

Comment: Ok. I got it.. It is ratingID.CurrentRating instead of value

Comment: Ok, great. So you can use that to store in db.

Comment: But the thing is it didn't inserted anything in db

Comment: Did you execute insert query? If so, it should insert.

Comment: Its correct though, you didn't pass userid, Hope that you know. Did you receive any error?

Comment: Yes I didn't passed userID now. First I want to check is it inserting data properly or not. Hence not receiving any errors

Comment: Well, you should receive any error, or data should inserted successfully. Can you please debug and check whats going there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105637/discussion-between-stupid-romeo-and-piyush-khatri).